# How can you trigger Android's numeric keypad AND Search button with HTML?

Tags: android, html

Using HTML, I know you can influence the Android keyboard's behavior.

For example, I can do something like this to get a numeric keyboard to show as well as accept zero-leading numbers (`type="number"` is an alternative option that strips leading zeroes in some cases):

```
<form>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Zip Code" required />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Additionally, I can do something like this to get a Search button on the Android keyboard (note the new `type`):

```
<form>
    <input type="search" placeholder="City" required />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to get both the numeric keyboard **and** search button via some other trick? I understand there may always be gotchas, and that's fine. Just looking to see if I can do better or if I'm forced to just pick one of my two above examples?

Comment: Your results will vary by browser and by input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard). There is no requirement for any of your `type` attributes to be honored in the way that you are expecting.

Comment: I definitely understand that. Like I said in my question, I understand that there are those types of "gotchas" and that's fine. Not looking for a 100% solution but just for the best I can do. Can I do better than the examples I posted?